# How to change retention duration for Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

At the moment most of the data retained for 90 days by default. I was wondering if there way to change this setting to 30-40 days. I know that I can export them to keep the data longer but what I'm looking for is mainly keep the data for shorter duration for the upcoming regulations.

Comment: If you want to join the variable retention preview, go to the [variable retention UserVoice request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/17454031) to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now available as an option in the Azure portal. If not, you need to get in touch with Azure support to get it activated.

Comment: Care to share exactly where? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the Application Insights resource.
Edit: Nevermind, found it! :) It is a button on top inside "Usage and estemated costs" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#change-the-data-retention-period

Answer (score 12):

**Update**

The default retention for Application Insights resources is `90 days`. Different retention periods can be selected for each Application Insights resource. The full set of available retention periods is **30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 270, 365, 550 or 730 days.**

*Note: If you need to keep data longer than 730 days, you can use [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) to copy it to a storage account during data ingestion.*

To change the retention, from your Application Insights resource, go to the **Usage and Estimated Costs page** and select the **Data Retention option**:

[image]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#change-the-data-retention-period)

Comment: One thing to add. This option is only available for the classic version of app insights. If you point your app insights resource to a log analytics workspace, the option will be greyed out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read from this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-retention-archive?tabs=portal-1%2Cportal-2 that we can keep data in interactive retention between 4 and 730 days. I cant find any option to set the retention to 4 days. Would you please tell me where it is.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the only answer is a no. In this case, you can't. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy#how-long-is-the-data-kept):

> Raw data points (that is, items that you can query in Analytics and inspect in Search) are kept for up to 90 days. If you need to keep data longer than that, you can use continuous export to copy it to a storage account.
>   Aggregated data (that is, counts, averages and other statistical data that you see in Metric Explorer) are retained at a grain of 1 minute for 90 days.

I remember that a long time ago the [pricing tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-insights/) dictated the maximum retention period but it is now fixed to 90 days for all plans.

You can try give your feedback / ask for this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights).

Comment: According to this, such a feature is currently under development: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/17454031-variable-data-retention-longer-or-shorter-than-th